# left_join from dplyr package produces NA results in the new column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, left-join, na

When I produce left_join (left_join from package dplyr)
of the below given data frames , the result (i.e.,)the new column after the join tends to be NA.

The columns 'V1','V1_1','V1_2','V1_3' are factors from data frames "df1" and "df2" respectively. By converting them to characters following warning message was removed which had occurred earlier.

> Warning message:
>
> In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) :
>   joining character vector and factor, coercing into character vector

Yet after removing warnings and clean run of the code, new column after join produces NA. 
I am not able to rectify what is going wrong . Any sort of help is appreciated.

> ### df1
>
> ```
>   V1    V2
> A415Z   1.01
> A415J   0.91
> B416X   0.95
> B416Z   0.97
> B416J   1.03
> B416M   1.16
> B416P  11.75
> B416W   0.98
> D420R   0.98
> D420H   0.94
> D420Z   1.01
> D420J   1.01
> D420F   0.90
> D420L   1.00
> C462H   0.93
> C462P   0.83
> C462W   0.73
> ```
>
> ### df2
>
> ```
>  V1_1  V1_2  V1_3
> A415Z B416P D420R
> A415Z B416P D420H
> A415Z B416P D420Z
> A415Z B416P D420J
> A415Z B416P D420F
> A415Z B416P D420L
> A415Z B416P C462H
> A415Z B416P C462P
> A415Z B416P C462W
> A415J B416P D420R
> A415J B416P D420H
> A415J B416P D420Z
> A415J B416P D420J
> A415J B416P D420F
> A415J B416P D420L
> A415J B416P C462H
> A415J B416P C462P
> A415J B416P C462W
> B416P D420R C462H
> B416P D420R C462P
> B416P D420R C462W
> B416P D420H C462H
> B416P D420H C462P
> B416P D420H C462W
> B416P D420Z C462H
> B416P D420Z C462P
> B416P D420Z C462W
> B416P D420J C462H
> B416P D420J C462P
> B416P D420J C462W
> B416P D420F C462H
> B416P D420F C462P
> B416P D420F C462W
> B416P D420L C462H
> B416P D420L C462P
> B416P D420L C462W
> ```
>
> code:
>
> library(dplyr)
>
> newdf<-left_join(df2,df1,by=c("V1_1"="V1"))
>
> ### output
>
> ```
>    V1_1  V1_2  V1_3 V2
>   A415Z B416P D420R NA
>   A415Z B416P D420H NA
>   A415Z B416P D420Z NA
>   A415Z B416P D420J NA
>   A415Z B416P D420F NA
>   A415Z B416P D420L NA
>   A415Z B416P C462H NA
>   A415Z B416P C462P NA
>   A415Z B416P C462W NA
>   A415J B416P D420R NA
>   A415J B416P D420H NA
>   A415J B416P D420Z NA
>   A415J B416P D420J NA
>   A415J B416P D420F NA
>   A415J B416P D420L NA
>   A415J B416P C462H NA
>   A415J B416P C462P NA
>   A415J B416P C462W NA
>   B416P D420R C462H NA
>   B416P D420R C462P NA
>   B416P D420R C462W NA
>   B416P D420H C462H NA
>   B416P D420H C462P NA
>   B416P D420H C462W NA
>   B416P D420Z C462H NA
>   B416P D420Z C462P NA
>   B416P D420Z C462W NA
>   B416P D420J C462H NA
>   B416P D420J C462P NA
>   B416P D420J C462W NA
>   B416P D420F C462H NA
>   B416P D420F C462P NA
>   B416P D420F C462W NA
>   B416P D420L C462H NA
>   B416P D420L C462P NA
>   B416P D420L C462W NA
> ```

Desired output should contain the column V2 from "df1" values adjoined to the "df2".

Comment: Change the factor class to character and join.  Also, check if there are leading/lagging spaces in one of the dataset columns i.e. `df1 %>% mutate(V1_1= trimws(as.character(V1_1))); df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(V1 = trimws(as.character(V1)));left_join(df1,df2,by=c("V1_1"="V1"))`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `left_join(df1,df2,by=c("V1"="V1_1"‌​))` or `left_join(df2,df1,by=c("V1_1"="V1"‌​))` ?

Comment: It works perfect after adding your code @ akrun, hence i guess there was only problem with extra spaces.