# dplyr::left_join() produces missing values on new columns and/or duplicated columns

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, left-join

I'm merging two dataframe objects using `dplyr`'s `left_join()` function, but it produces `NA` in newly created columns. Sometimes it did produce merged data with actual values but merged columns are duplicated unless I use `merge` without specifying `type` argument.
I've referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016377/dplyrleft-join-produce-na-values-for-new-joined-columns) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933682/left-join-from-dplyr-package-produces-na-results-in-the-new-column) threads, but I am certain that my match id variables are of the same character class and all in upper case letters. I'm wondering what went wrong.

Below are my data sources and code example:

```r
# data
country_dyad <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/q0ivr9d3lgjpdlxq88a4u/country_dyad.rds?rlkey=vc4i6j7bgbd3xaftkdk4yqhny&dl=1"))
trade <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/wxism5ytikswdhyy27rle/trade.rds?rlkey=aonsyj1q2uied1t8y9necsuk0&dl=1"))


merge <- left_join(country_dyad, trade, by = c("REPORTER", "PARTNER"))

merge

   REPORTER PARTNER Chapter_ID Chapter_sum
1       afg     afg         NA          NA
2       alb     afg         NA          NA
3       ago     afg         NA          NA
4       atg     afg         NA          NA
5       arg     afg         NA          NA
6       arm     afg         NA          NA
7       aus     afg         NA          NA
8       aut     afg         NA          NA
9       bhr     afg         NA          NA
10      bgd     afg         NA          NA

# left_join(country_dyad, trade, by = c("REPORTER", "PARTNER"))
# This will produce duplicated columns
```

Comment: `identical(country_dyad, trade)` returns `TRUE`. I think you need to change the link to `country_dyad`.

Comment: It is the same link. But please use `dput(country_dyad)` and `dput(trade)` outputs for sharing your example data,  especially when dealing with tiny ~10-row frames.

Comment: @Friede It's been updated.

Comment: By visual inspection, there are no equal combinations of `REPORTER` and `PARTNER` between the two data frames. Merging on those does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Friede They should be equal. `setdiff(country_dyad$REPORTER, trade$REPORTER)` returns `character(0)`.

Comment: @ChrisT., for me `setdiff(country_dyad$REPORTER, trade$REPORTER)` returns `c("afg", "atg", "arg", "arm", "aus", "aut", "bhr", "bgd")`. I think `intersect` is a better indicator of whether we can get non-`NA` values, in which case `intersect(country_dyad$REPORTER, trade$REPORTER)` returns `c("alb", "ago")`. However, that's just one of your two join fields, and there are no _pairs_ of countries in `country_dyad` that also exist as a _pair_ of countries in `trade`. Your results are all `NA` here because your data have no shared country pairs.

Comment: @r2evans Ok, I'll have a second look.

Answer (score 0):

**You can always just click on the data and have an inspection.**

They are tiny data frames, so it is not difficult to see there is no common combinations of `"REPORTER"` column and `"PARTNER"` column over two datasets. The first two columns in your results are essentially the whole `country_dyad`. The values in `PARTNER` column of `trade` are everyhthing but `"afg"`.

Note that `setdiff()` only shows the elements exclusively in the first group (i.e., not in the second group), but not the other way around. For example:

```
>setdiff(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,5)) 
[1] 3 4
```

3 and 4 are very straightforward, as they are not in the second vector, but note that `setdiff()` here doesn't give you 5. **This means `setdiff()` won't give you any idea that whether there are elements exclusively in the second group.**